# Show lemma on probability of $n$ independent sets

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

> Let be $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$ a probability space and $A_1,\dots ,A_n \in \mathcal{A}$. For sake of convenience we define $A^1:=A$ and $A^c:=\Omega\setminus A$. Let be $(k_1,\dots , k_n)\in\{1,c\}^n$. Show that
> $$
> A_1,\dots , A_n\text{ are stochastically independent }\implies P\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^n A_j^{k_j}\right)=\prod\limits_{j=1}^nP(A_j^{k_j}).
> $$

**My approach:**

*base case of induction*:

Let be $m$ the number of the "complement signs" $c$. If $n=1$, then the equation obviuously holds for each $m$ with $0\leq m\leq 1$.

*induction hypothesis*:

We assume that the equation holds if we consider $n$-many stocastically independent sets $A_1,\dots A_n$ and $m$-many complement signs, with $0\leq m\leq n$.

*induction step* $n\to n+1$, with $0\leq m\leq n+1$:

\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} A_j^{k_j}\right)=P\left(\bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{n} A_j^{k_j}\cap A_{n+1}^{k_{n+1}}\right)=\dots?
\end{align*}

---

Now, I am a bit lost because it seems like I should perform another induction on $m$. However, this would require a second induction hypothesis like "the equation holds in the case of $n+1$ and $0\leq m\leq n$" which would beg the question.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Check Theorem 4.2 of *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley.  In there, let $\mathscr{A}_i = \{A_i\}$, then the result follows.

Comment: The machinery of proving this theorem is $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, not induction.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, hmm the hint our Tutor gave us was "use induction". So was she wrong?

Comment: Induction may work (I tried for a while but did not work out), but definitely will not be as clean as the theorem I referenced.

Comment: Induction is the most elementary approach. I assume the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem can be used too, but I doubt it can be done in a way that is cleaner than induction (unless it relies on a bunch of unproven stuff).

Comment: @Adayah I upvoted your proof, which is very clever (induction on $m$).  My previous statement was careless (as I was thinking induction on $n$).  On the other hand, I guess the advantage of the proof with $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem is in its generality.  And the treatment is very canonical in advanced measure-theoretic probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction on $m$ is sufficient: we show by induction on $m$ that for each number $n \geqslant m$, stochastically independent sets $A_1, \ldots, A_n \in \mathcal{A}$ and $k \in \{ 1, c \}^n$ containing $m$-many complement symbols the equality from the question holds.

For $m=0$ the claim is trivial. Fix $m \geqslant 1$, assume the claim holds for $m-1$ and take $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ and $k \in \{ 1, c \}^n$ as in the statement. By symmetry we can assume that $k_n = c$. We have that

$$\bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} = \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n \right) \cup \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n^c \right)$$

and the sets on the right are disjoint, so

$$P \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \right) = P\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n \right) + P\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n^c \right).$$

The first two probabilities can be computed using the induction hypothesis since among the "exponents" there are exactly $m-1$-many complement signs:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} P(A_j^{k_j}) = \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} P(A_j^{k_j}) \cdot P(A_n) + P\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n^c \right).$$

It follows that

$$P\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^n A_j^{k_j} \right) = P\left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \cap A_n^c \right) = \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} P(A_j^{k_j}) \cdot \big(1-P(A_n)\big) = \prod_{j=1}^n P(A_j^{k_j}),$$

as desired.

Comment: I don't see why an induction solely on $m$ is sufficient. In particular, why are you allowed to apply the induction hypothesis at $P \left( \bigcap_{j=1}^{n-1} A_j^{k_j} \right) $? It consists of $(n-1)$-many sets and $(m-1)$-many complement signs. The induction hypothesis on $m$ requires $n$-many sets and $(m-1)$-many complement signs. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Philipp It's because of the way induction statement is formulated. The number $n$ is not globally fixed; it is universally quantified inside the induction statement. Therefore the induction hypothesis for $m-1$ asserts that given an arbitrary number $n'$ the equality will hold for any (s.i.) $n'$-many sets. Now when I prove the statement for $m$, I fix arbitrary $n$-many s.i. sets and apply the hypothesis twice, one of which is for $n' := n-1$.

Comment: It's a very common technique when proving a statement of the form $(\forall x \in X)(\forall m \in \mathbb{N}) \, \varphi(m, x)$ by induction on $m$, to formulate the induction statement as $T(m): (\forall x \in X) \, \varphi(m, x)$. As a result, while proving $T(m)$ by fixing $x \in X$ and trying to show $\varphi(m, x)$, the induction hypothesis asserts that $\varphi(m-1, y)$ holds for every possible $y \in X$, not just for $y=x$.